# Custom tags in UiBinder files

Tags: gwt, uibinder

When using a `<g:LayoutPanel>` in UiBinder.ui.xml files, you can specify `<g:layer>` tags.  Some other Google-built widgets have special tags like that as well - `<g:tab>` even has a sub-tag, `<g:header>`.

How can I specify these for my own widgets?

Comment: The question is still interesting two years later: do you know about any improvements?

Comment: Yes, there are definite improvements: look up @UiChild

Comment: In fact, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/11785903/439317

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new answer to this question, after some GWT improvements, is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11785903/439317 .  Copied below to avoid moderator deletion (maybe?).

You can use @UiChild to declare special functions in your widgets accessible in UiBinders.

for example,

```
class MyPanel extends AbsolutePanel {

    @UiChild
    public void addAt(Widget w, String parameter1, String parameter2) {
         ....
```

Then, in your uiBinder, you can say

```
<custom:MyPanel>
    <custom:at parameter1="HI" parameter2="Anything you like!">
        <g:AnySingleWidget />
    </custom:at>
</custom:MyPanel>
```

See @UiChild at http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/UiChild.html

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a custom element parser for UiBinder. See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4461). Unfortunately it's not supported yet.

You might be interested in [this post](https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit-contributors/browse_thread/thread/4d79f729030527c5/181973c17d16cbc0?lnk=gst&q=custom+element+parser#181973c17d16cbc0) for some guidance on how to extend the current parser on your own.