# Adding items to custom widget in GWT UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I created a custom form dropdown widget in GWT.  Basically it is a list box with some bells and whistles attached to it.  I would like to add items to the list box using the UiBinder.  If it was just a gwt ListBox I could have

```
<g:ListBox>
  <g:item>Test</g:item>
  <g:item>Test</g:item>
</g:ListBox>
```

and all is good.  In the same spirit I would like my custom widget to also aceppt adding items like:

```
<my:FormDropdown>
  <g:item>Test</g:item>
  <g:item>Test</g:item>
</my:FormDropdown>
```

I don't need it to be g:item that I add to it incase I need to make a custom  thing.  I think I need to use GWT UiBinder factory methods, but I can't find a location in the GWT UiBinder docs that discusses this.

Answer (score 2):

Add a namespace declaration to your `<ui:Binder .... >` tag at the top of the UIBinder XML like this:

```xml
xmlns:my="urn:import:com.yourcompany.yourproject.widgets"
```

You are adding an XML namespace, that points to the package containing `FormDropdown.java`.

So if your `FormDropdown` is in: `com.yourcompany.yourproject.widgets.FormDropdown.java`

Then your UI Binder XML should say:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui" 
    xmlns:my="urn:import:com.yourcompany.yourproject.widgets">
    <ui:style>
    .important {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </ui:style>
    <g:HTMLPanel>

        <my:FormDropdown>
            <g:item>Test</g:item>
            <g:item>Test</g:item>
        </my:FormDropdown>

    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: Not the question.  How can i get my:dropdown to add g:items or something similar?

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13846858/1038832

GWT ListBox does it with an element parser (see `com.google.gwt.uibinder.elementparsers.ListBoxParser`).